# Retrieving the newly-generated _id when inserting through Shell

Tags: mongodb

This might be trivial, but when running 'insert' from **Mongodb shell**, I can't seem to retrieve the newly-generated _id :

```
db.coll.insert({someField:"someValue"});
var theId=??? /* How to get the _id of my newly inserted object? */
```

I know how to retrieve it through language specific drivers (java, node.js) but not from the **Shell**. So far I eliminated the following :

```
var x=db.coll.insert(...)
print(x);
// Doesn't work: x is undefined

var doc={...}
db.coll.insert(doc);
print(doc._id)
// Doesn't work, prints undefined
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`var doc={...}
db.coll.save(doc);
print(doc._id)`

Note that [db.collection.save()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/) will update a document if it finds a match by _id. In your case, it will do an insert.

Honestly, I'm not quite sure why `db.collection.insert()` doesn't populate `_id` in your in-memory document...

Comment: looking into the source of db.books.save exactly verifies what you said. Thanks again.